# Android: How to create round view frame?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, shapes

In android, I want to have a view with a round frame, so I could place another view inside it and get a masked effect.

Current situation:

[image: blue circle is the parent, purple is the child]

I want the blue circle to have a round frame, allowing this:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to achieve that, without using images?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This view works for you.
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/BezelImageView.java

It clip bitmap using the mask defined by you.If you want to achieve your goal,you can use it like these below:

```
<BezelImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content”   
    app:maskDrawable="@drawable/default_circle_mask"
/>
```

default_circle_mask.drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#000" />
```